# Python brings up the help menu in PyCharm

Tags: python, input

In my class called Commands, I have a "carstuff" command (it's a very basic command system) which is supposed to bring up my help menu, but instead it just brings up the python help menu. Here's my commands.py file:

```
class Commands:
    pass


    def askCommand(self):
        command = input("Enter command:  ")
        if command == "carstuff":
            #the other part that's having problems
            help()
        elif command == "sell":
            pass
        elif command == "addcar":
            pass


    #part that's having problems
    def help(self):
        print(
            "carstuff: Brings up the help menu\nsell: Sells the current car\naddcar: Adds another car"
        )
```

And here's my main.py file (I'm making a mockup of craigslist)

```
from car import Car
from commands import Commands


print("Welcome to Craigslist on the command line! Start by entering your car info below.")

brand = input("Enter your car brand: ")
model = input("Enter your car model: ")
year = input("Enter your car's year: ")
condition = input("Enter your car's condition: ")

car = Car(brand, model, year, condition)

print("Your car's price is: " + str(car.price))

print("Now that you've listed your car, you can use commands now!\n")

command = Commands.askCommand(Commands)
```

And I have another car.py file (but I don't know if it will be of any use)

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, brand, model, year, condition):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.condition = condition
        self.price = len(model) * 0.75 * 3000
        if self.condition == "Bad":
            self.price - 100
        elif self.condition == "Brand New":
            self.price + 100




    def Sell(self):
        sure = input("Are you sure you want to sell? (Y/N): ")
        if sure == "Y" or "y":
            self.sellprice = self.price % 75
            print("You got " + self.sellprice + " from this car.")
        elif sure == "N" or "n":
            print("Sell cancelled.\n")
```

Comment: Try replacing `help()` with `self.help()` in your `askCommand` method.

Comment: if i do that i get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adisa\PycharmProjects\craigslist\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    command = Commands.askCommand(Commands)
  File "C:\Users\adisa\PycharmProjects\craigslist\commands.py", line 14, in askCommand
    self.help()
TypeError: Commands.help() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self

Comment: @kooljcid - have you tried instantiating the Commands class first? `commands = Commands()` followed by `command = commands.askCommand()`

Comment: Also try removing "pass" from under commands class.